# MySQL: best practice for querying last value before a certain date in a time series

Tags: mysql, select, query-optimization

I have the following table in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `history` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `timestamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `code` CHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    `value` FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `timestamp_code` (`timestamp`, `code`),
    INDEX `code` (`code`),
    INDEX `timestamp` (`timestamp`)
   ) COLLATE='utf8_general_ci' ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I would like to know what is the best practice in order to access the last available value before a certain date for a certain set of codes the most efficiently?

So far I came up with the following query:

```
SELECT h.* FROM history h
JOIN (
    SELECT code, MAX(timestamp) as 'last_ts'
    FROM history WHERE
    timestamp < '2015-09-04 13:50:00' AND
    code IN ('119813249', '12087792', '12087797',
    '127012151', '131014335', '131014378',
    '132757371', '15016059', '15016062',
    '150250238', '153462747', '155802712',
    '156974389', '162277696', '166330444',
    '166483001', '167220356', '167264923',
    '167867931', '172283682', '177539478',
    '177583937', '177648754', '177649011',
    '187532416', '189230667', '70273253',
    '70342790', '79342386', '82460282',
    '98693280', '98693380')
    GROUP BY code) last_price
ON last_price.last_ts = h.timestamp
AND last_price.code = h.code
```

The query above works, but becomes slow as the number of entries in the table grows (100'000'000 rows).

You can download [sample data](http://wikisend.com/download/504186/samples.sql) to populate the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an index by code, timestamp - rather than timestamp, code. This would let mysql sort out codes before looking for the max timestamp per code - and should be much faster. Use explain for verifying that the index is used.

And if you create that index - you should not have to modify your query.